# Laravel InfluxDB Eloquent

Tags: laravel, influxdb

Can I use Laravel Model/Eloquent with a NoSQL DB, in this case InfluxDB?

I will have a Device model like this

```
class Element extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $primaryKey = 'id'; // or null
    public $incrementing = false;
    
    protected $keyType = 'string';    
    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'top',
        'left',
        'temperature',
        'power'
    ];
}
```

But each of the attributes will be a meassurement of the Influx Database.